# Securing an Individual View/Page or admin section in a single page application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

So here's the problem. I have a an admin section on my asp.net mvc website that uses single page applications to edit the tables in a database. Now there is nothing to prevent someone from going to the admin section and seeing those single page apps. They won't be able to do anything because the Web API is secure on the back end. I'm trying to think of the best way to secure those admin page single page apps.

The Web API uses the new ASP.NET Identity feature for security which is pretty straight forward to do. I could use ASP.NET Identity also on the mvc site. When someone requests one of the views for a single page app, they would be redirected to a login page.  This would leave me a website that is a hybrid of single page apps with a traditional mvc website for the individual page security. Is this ok to do or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you use a consistent approach to your authorization, you definitely want to be securing your controller and Web API methods separately. The 'hybrid' is fine as long as you keep consistent, say with attribute based authorization checks.

If you only have a few roles to work with, you can use the standard Authorize attribute:

```
[Authorize( Roles = Constants.ADMIN )]
```

If you've got something more complicated going on, consider a custom Authorize attribute:

```
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //something more complex here
    }
}
```